# Verifying Ubuntu ISO with `md5sum` - does the missing "*" matter?

Tags: iso, md5sum

I'm trying to understand security and verification a bit more so I've been playing with getting random ISOs and verifying them with `md5sum`.

For instance if I download the [Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 release](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuGNOME/GetUbuntuGNOME) to `~/Downloads` I can run the following:

```
cd ~/Downloads
md5sum ubuntu-gnome-15.10-desktop-amd64.iso
```

Which after a brief pause to crunch numbers, gives me the following result:

```
b89cd1cee3acc2ec174f8d995bd74794  ubuntu-gnome-15.10-desktop-amd64.iso
```

When I check this against the [Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 published MD5 hashes](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-gnome/releases/15.10/release/MD5SUMS) I get something nearly but not quite the same:

```
b89cd1cee3acc2ec174f8d995bd74794 *ubuntu-gnome-15.10-desktop-amd64.iso
97b49f32a70b46537c34e24e43c16526 *ubuntu-gnome-15.10-desktop-i386.iso
```

Can anyone explain the origin, meaning or reason for this mysterious "*"?

My understanding is that these are supposed to be identical... the only thing standing between that and me is this wildcard, so what's up with that?

Comment: You're right to be cautious, though [as kos said](https://askubuntu.com/a/700798), the only thing that really matters is that the _hashes_ of the files match. That said, while (as far as I know) there are no _practical_ preimage attacks against MD5, there _is_ [a _theoretical_ one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5?oldid=691114726#Preimage_vulnerability), and I believe the general consensus is that, for pure hashes, MD5 should be avoided in favor of SHA (and preferably at least SHA-2). Personally, MD5's theoretical vulnerability is enough to make me use something better whenever possible.

Comment: It seems to me you could simply have read the documentation?

Comment: *playing with getting random ISOs* You sure have a lot of bandwidth to spare...

Comment: @BlacklightShining very interesting links many thanks I'll explore getting to grips with SHA-2 in future.

Comment: @ace :) fringe benefits to filling a hard drive with ISOs due to chronic indecisiveness about ubuntu flavours.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It means the hash was calculated in binary mode.

> The default mode is to print a line with checksum, a character indicating type ('*' for binary, ' ' for text), and name for each FILE.

[Source](http://linux.die.net/man/1/md5sum)

As ISO files are binary, this is what you want.

Comment: +1 for the explanation of the "*", which I never grasped. However on systems using linefeed line-ending (Ubuntu) there's no difference between text files and binary files, in fact `md5sum` runs by default in text mode; despite, OP's output hash matches the hash calculated in binary mode.

Comment: Fantastic, great answers from both you and @kos that explains what's going on and sets my mind at ease that I'm not getting md5 hashes wrong. Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

> Verifying Ubuntu ISO with `md5sum` - does the missing "*" matter?

No.

In the output of `md5sum` the first column lists the calculated MD5 sum(s) and the second column lists the filename(s) corresponding to the calculated MD5 sum(s) listed on the left column;

The second column is irrelevant for the purpose of checking the MD5 sum of a file <del>because it's just a mere report of the name of the file corresponding to the calculated MD5 sum reported on the first column</del>. <sub>In Ubuntu a present or a missing leading "*" is irrelevant, however the previous statement is not correct: see [Louis Matthijssen](https://askubuntu.com/a/700833/380067)'s answer for an explanation of the difference between a missing and a present leading "*".</sub>

The filename is a filesystem metadata and has nothing to do with the "raw" file, which is the only thing really checked (and really relevant) when checking the MD5 sum of a file;

You could rename your ISO `foo.iso` and its MD5 sum would still match `b89cd1cee3acc2ec174f8d995bd74794`, which means that the file matches the expected MD5 sum.